# What changes does Lockheed's fusion concept have which makes it better than magnetic mirrors?

Tags: magnetic-fields, plasma-physics, fusion

Magnetic mirrors were thought to be a viable solution for fusion power. But then, we found out that most of the plasma would simply escape. Is this  right? So, then we realized that this  method might not  work. So after many years, Lockheed has come up with a similar model.

[image]

- Lockheeds model is a cusp confinement device. It creates null points and the field lines get denser as we move out radially. But along the axis, we have open field lines and plasma can escape along those lines. Now, according to what I read, lockheed uses magnetic coils to create a magnetic mirror effect. Hence, the particles would just get reflected.

[image]

But what I don't understand is, didn't we try magnetic mirrors before and learn that they are not the best? Lockheed just added cusps which in my opinion just makes it worse because the plasma can also leak through the cusps and not just through the sides.

- My question is, what changes in the model did lockheed bring in to make a working model. Did they introduce any other aspects that aid in plasma confinement that I am not aware of? Or is it just this? But wouldn't it most likely fail if there are no  new ideas other that the cusps and mirrors involved?

Comment: It is my understanding that the Lockheed Martin reactor is very different than a classical mirror machine.  It is in the [Field Reversed Configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field-reversed_configuration) (FRC).  LM is only one of several organizations exploring small fusion options, including other FRC efforts.

Comment: Oh! never knew that, but how do they do it if the coils are placed according to the diagram?

Comment: first of all, we should be aware that LM is still lacking a proper publication of experimental results (please correct me if I am wrong). Then, their idea (keep in mind, unproven) is to introduce an additional magnetic well in the center by the internal coils, thus a field reversed configuration. As you said, they mostly combine old techniques which were abandoned decades ago in fusion research (due to little prospect of success). Apart from that, internal coils in a hot plasma environment is problematic, too